# Generating unique ids and group ids using dplyr and concatenation

Tags: r, crash, dplyr

I have a problem that I suspect has arisen from a `dplyr` update combined with my hacky code. Given a data frame in which every row is duplicated, I want to assign each row a unique id by combining the entries of two columns with either "_" or "a_" in the middle. I also want to assign a group id by combining the entries of one column with either "" or "a". Because these formats are important for lining up with another data frame, I can't use solutions based on `interact` and `factor` that I've seen in other posts.

So I want to go from this:

```
   Generation Identity
1           1        X
2           1        Y
3           1        Z
4           2        X
5           2        Y
6           2        Z
7           3        X
8           3        Y
9           3        Z
10          1        X
11          1        Y
12          1        Z
13          2        X
14          2        Y
15          2        Z
16          3        X
17          3        Y
18          3        Z
```

to this:

```
   Generation Identity Unique_id Group_id
1           1        X        1_X        X
2           1        Y        1_Y        Y
3           1        Z        1_Z        Z
4           2        X        2_X        X
5           2        Y        2_Y        Y
6           2        Z        2_Z        Z
7           3        X        3_X        X
8           3        Y        3_Y        Y
9           3        Z        3_Z        Z
10          1        X        1a_X        Xa
11          1        Y        1a_Y        Ya
12          1        Z        1a_Z        Za
13          2        X        2a_X        Xa
14          2        Y        2a_Y        Ya
15          2        Z        2a_Z        Za
16          3        X        3a_X        Xa
17          3        Y        3a_Y        Ya
18          3        Z        3a_Z        Za
```

The minimal example below is based on code that previously worked for me and others in setting the unique id but that now causes RStudio to crash with a seg fault (Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)). When I call a function containing this code it generates the message

> Error in match(vector, df$Unique_id) : 'translateCharUTF8' must be
>   called on a CHARSXP

which I've read can be symptomatic of memory issues.

```
library(dplyr)
dff <- data.frame(Generation = rep(1:3, each = 3), 
  Identity = rep(LETTERS[24:26], times = 3))
dff <- rbind(dff, dff) # duplicate rows
dff <- group_by_(dff, ~Generation, ~Identity) %>% 
  mutate(Unique_id = c(paste0(Identity[1], "_", Generation[1]), paste0(Identity[1], "a", "_", Generation[1]))) %>% 
  ungroup
```

I think the problem is related to an update of `dplyr` (I'm using the latest release versions of RStudio and all packages, on OSX Sierra). In any case, my solution above is something of a hack. I'd very much appreciate suggestions for improved code, preferably using either base R or dplyr (since the code is part of a package that currently depends on dplyr).

Comment: What about `df %>% group_by(Generation,Identity) %>% mutate(Unique_id=paste0(Generation,c("_","a_"),Identity),Group_id=paste0(Identity,c("","a")))`, does it still throw an error?

Comment: I think whatever causes this error may have been fixed in the development version of *dplyr* (your code works for me using that).  See [this closed issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2971)

Comment: Thanks @aosmith for the link. Indeed my problem may be related to the closed issue with dplyr, though I'll need to do more testing to be confident of that. Like breichholf, I've had trouble reproducing the error, which can come and go on the same system (but isn't unique to my machine). Until version 0.7.3 is released, I'll recommend users of my package to use it with the development version (or an older version) of dplyr.

Comment: And thanks @Lamia for the neat suggestion. Definitely an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can approach the problem:

First find the duplicates of your data. I called my data `A`

```
 dup=duplicated(A)
```

Then add a counter row:

```
 A$count=1:nrow(A)
n=ncol(A)#THE COLUMN ADDED
```

now obtain the two columns needed and cbind it with the original dataframe:

```
     B=data.frame(t(apply(A,1,function(x)
        if(dup[as.numeric(x[n])]) c(paste0(x["Identity"],"a"),paste(x[-n],collapse="a_")) 
        else c(x["Identity"],paste(x[-n],collapse="_")))))

  `names<-`(cbind(A[-n],B),c(names(A[-1]),"Group_ID","Unique_ID"))
    Identity count Group_ID Unique_ID
 1         1     X        X       1_X
 2         1     Y        Y       1_Y
 3         1     Z        Z       1_Z
 4         2     X        X       2_X
 5         2     Y        Y       2_Y
 6         2     Z        Z       2_Z
 7         3     X        X       3_X
 8         3     Y        Y       3_Y
 9         3     Z        Z       3_Z
 10        1     X       Xa      1a_X
 11        1     Y       Ya      1a_Y
 12        1     Z       Za      1a_Z
 13        2     X       Xa      2a_X
 14        2     Y       Ya      2a_Y
 15        2     Z       Za      2a_Z
 16        3     X       Xa      3a_X
 17        3     Y       Ya      3a_Y
 18        3     Z       Za      3a_Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my amended version of Onyambu's solution, which refers to columns by name rather than number (and so can handle data frames that have additional columns):

```
dup <- duplicated(dff) # identify duplicates
dff$count <- 1:nrow(dff) # add count column to the dataframe

# create a new dataframe containing the unique and group ids:
B <- data.frame(t(apply(dff, 1, function(x)
  if(dup[as.numeric(x["count"])]) c(paste0(x["Identity"], "a"), 
  paste(x["Identity"], x["Generation"], sep = "a_")) 
  else c(x["Identity"], paste(x["Identity"], x["Generation"], sep = "_")))))

# combine the dataframes:
colnames(B) <- c("Group_id", "Unique_id")
dff <- cbind(dff[-ncol(dff), B)
```